# Timer combined Application.DoEvents is not working

Tags: c#, .net, com

In my application, I am dealing with so many datas. So it is freezing when it deals with the data. So I am having a timer. I am calling Application.DoEvents in the timer's elapsed event. Code is below

```
    class StoSCorrelation : Reports
    {
        double timer_Interval = 5;
        public System.Timers.Timer timer;
        public StoSCorrelation()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timer_Interval);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
        //The below function freezes the screen
        public bool generateReport()
        {
            try
            {
                timer.Enabled = true;
                //deal with the data
                if (//some condition)
                {
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                //Log
                timer.Enabled = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

So, I expected the screen won't freeze. But still it is freezing. I checked with messagebox to know whether the timer triggered in the interval. It seems it is happening. But still the screen freezes. I want to know why? and how to clear this problem. I want my screen to be active.
Note:Threading is not done. I am using C# 3.5, windows 10 pro,VS 2008.

Comment: The Elapsed event handler runs on a thread-pool thread.  Calling DoEvents on that thread does nothing at all, the thread is not running a dispatcher loop.  None of the timers can solve this problem, you instead must run the slow code on a worker thread so it won't freeze the UI.

Comment: @Hans Give it as answer. This is the answer I was seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running the heavy task(s) in the GUI thread.

I would not use a timer to keep the GUI going, since the timer will run in the GUI thread.
The GUI will not respond to Application.DoEvents(); when it hangs.
I would rather use multithreading on the heavy tasks.

This could get you started:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm